# Проблемы с переадресацией с http на https

Tags: php, linux, centos, apache2, centos7

Переадресация работает только с корня сайта. 
httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect ^/?(.*) https://example.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
    ServerName example.com

    SSLEngine on

    # SSLRequireSSL
    # SSLVerifyClient require

    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/comodo.crt

    #ServerAlias www.example.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/example.com">
        allow from all
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/error.log

    php_admin_flag register_globals 1
    php_admin_value max_execution_time 60
    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 10M
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403
# Disable magic quotes
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime 0

# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php?q=$0

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<Files config.php>
deny from all
</Files>
<Files M*.php>
deny from all
</Files>
<Files C*.php>
deny from all
</Files>
<Files v*.php>
deny from all
</Files>
AddType application/octet-stream .txt
AddType application/octet-stream .exe
AddType application/octet-stream .npk
AddType application/octet-stream .rsc
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: [When redirecting everything you don't even need a DocumentRoot](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL#Using_virtual_hosts_.28using_redirect.29): `servername example.com\n redirect / https://example.com`

Comment: http://joxi.ru/gmvpE6jcLyO50A

Comment: так уберите то, что вы нагородили в `.htaccess`

Comment: Подскажите что именно убрать в .htaccess?

Comment: Я только начинаю разбираться с Apache

Comment: если только начинаете, то зачем начинаете с хаков типа использования `.htaccess` вместо нормальной конфигурации?

Comment: убрать лучше всё, кроме того, что невозможно реализовать в конф. файле (мне, кстати, такого не известно).

Comment: для справки: `.htaccess` — это костыль, исключительно apache-вское изобретение для того, чтобы не давать пользователям прав вносить изменения в конфигурацию программы.